# Winter Bash 2015 - the Hat Competition

Tags: discussion, hats, winter-bash

The last three years SP.SE participated in **Winter Bash**, which lets our users earn and wear hats on their user profile image. You earn hats through participation in asking questions, answering questions, getting up-votes, voting, commenting and sharing to mention a few things. Exactly the same things you’re doing here to earn reputation and badges. However, there is a twist; you don’t know what will earn hats. Suddenly, it just appears in a hat-gallery where you can pick the hat of the day. It’s all up to you, hat or no hat. You can choose not to wear any of earned hats.

Winter Bash is a fun, lighthearted event we run every year as a way of celebrating the many amazing people who make our communities awesome.

Therefore, we’re announcing **Winter Bash 2015**!

## Winter Bash Leaderboard

[image]

## Winter Bash Hats Collection (2014)

A few of the available hats
[image]
[image]

## Winter Bash Hat Example (2014)

[image] [image] [image] [image]

## Details

This event will run from December 14 to January 3, 2016. Users will be able to see their entire hat collection on http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/. That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and other details of the event.

## Don’t like hats?

Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option available. And just like last time, at the end of the event, all hats will go back into storage.

The only visual change to the SP.SE will be the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the footer.

Comment: With the Carl hat, you are almost identical to a teacher I had many years ago.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist I am your teacher ;-)

Comment: *a year later* Would you get mad if I try something a little different this year for the usual announcement? Just to break the monotony...

Comment: @SPArchaeologist No, in fact - I'm working on it now. Have any smart suggestion? ;-)

Comment: actually, I was almost going to "steal" the announcement :P But I won't do that - it would feel pretty bad - even I you were to agree, it would still seem like a stolen badge ^_^

Comment: @SPArchaeologist LOL ;-)

Answer (score 6):

As every year I will be at the SugarCube chat room on the Meta StackExchange site. As every year, you would be welcome Benny... Will you drop to say "hi" this year? :P

Anyway, for now I am somehow satisfied. The specialist hat is identical to the one Fluttershy had back in season 1, so I can pretend it is a reference. Not a mayor one, but better than last year.

Anyway, back to hunt... even if I fear this year may be a quite harder than last one. Not saying that if you want to give 7 votes to this answer of mine while keeping 0 comments on this answer and the question I will get mad... I can always use a 007 hat.

PS:
On a related note, if anyone knows anything about this, any help is well accepted.
[The Quest for the Winter Chickens of the Bash](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270899/the-quest-for-the-winter-chickens-of-the-bash)

Comment: I'm in and I got a brand new hat to wear! See http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4355593#4355593 :-)

Comment: @BennySkogberg - Saw that Benny - sadly I am at the moment working out some chat problems. Why won't they make oneboxing optional...